# What is kedar-kalpa?

Tags: shiva, shaivism, manuscripts

[Here](https://www.niyogibooksindia.com/books/a-sacred-journey) it says -

> **The Kedar-Kalpa is a relatively little-known Shaiva text;**

What is the origin or source of this text, and what all information is available about it? Any extant manuscript?

Is it some sthala-purana type text, and how much authoritative it is considered within Shaiva community?